# Delete quagga/zebra route using ip route

Tags: routing, quagga

I have a DHCP client running on eth0 and eth1. zebra routes show up automatically when these interfaces get a lease. This is the output of ip route:

```
root@localhost:~# ip route
default  proto zebra 
  nexthop via 192.168.53.254  dev eth1 weight 1
  nexthop via 192.168.1.1  dev eth0 weight 1
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.133 
192.168.53.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.53.42
```

(TL;DR: how do I remove, say, the default route going thru 192.168.53.254 with ip route?)

Now, I'm doing my own PBR load balancing, and I need to take down a route when pinging through it doesn't work for some time. I'm doing

```
vtysh -c "configure terminal" -c "no ip route 0.0.0.0/0 $ROUTER"
```

which removes the route, but seems to confuse zebra because when I unplug the cable and replug it doesn't re-add the route automatically anymore. I figure removing the route with ip route won't confuse zebra as much, but for the life of me I can't figure out the correct syntax.

I tried

```
ip route del default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto zebra
```

which doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't do anything. I can see the route is still there if I do "ip route" afterwards.

Can anybody please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you telnet into quagga,

first:

> configure terminal

then:

> no ip route <...>

and replace `<...>` into your previous command

This will disable your previous command.

Answer (score -1):

After zebra process killed, you can flush zebra route by below command:

```sh
sudo ip route flush table main proto zebra
```